# Exclude specific lines in CSV

Tags: excel, csv

This is my first post here and I need some help with a CSV file.

I'm a VBA enthusiast and used to program in cobol and such stuff... Anyway, here is my problem:

I have a CSV file that imports product information (bags, wallets and other stuff) from the factory into our system, but we had a problem with the wallet container... So we excluded all wallets from the system, and now we need to import only those, creating purchase orders with wallets only... here is the issue:

```html
1;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;09/10/2019;02/12/2019 15:44:00;719;REPRESENTACOES COMERCIAIS;591;FL BRASIL HOLDING LOGISTICA E TRANSPORTE LTDA;1;Rodov.-CIF;;;;;28/56/84 DD C/ 6.5% AC;1775;NAME HERE;ROAD HERE;CENTRO;19200000;CITY;ST;CNPJ;;541009976115;CELLPHONE;;;;;;31;EMAIL
2;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;090.01.09292;0050;PRETO;BOLSA ENVELOPE FEM LETREIRO;U;1;28/01/2020;04/02/2020
2;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;090.01.09292;0050;PRETO;BOLSA ENVELOPE FEM LETREIRO;U;1;28/01/2020;04/02/2020
2;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;090.01.09292;0050;PRETO;BOLSA ENVELOPE FEM LETREIRO;U;1;28/01/2020;04/02/2020
1;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;09/10/2019;02/12/2019 15:44:00;719;REPRESENTACOES COMERCIAIS;591;FL BRASIL HOLDING LOGISTICA E TRANSPORTE LTDA;1;Rodov.-CIF;;;;;28/56/84 DD C/ 6.5% AC;1775;NAME HERE;ROAD HERE;CENTRO;19200000;CITY;ST;CNPJ;;541009976115;CELLPHONE;;;;;;31;EMAIL
2;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;090.01.09292;0050;PRETO;BOLSA ENVELOPE FEM LETREIRO;U;1;28/01/2020;04/02/2020
2;492;CNPJ;COMPANY;50;1207960;090.01.09292;0050;PRETO;BOLSA ENVELOPE FEM LETREIRO;U;1;28/01/2020;04/02/2020
```

So this is my CSV file in a nutshell (I modified it a bit to hide sensitive information), it uses 1 for Client information and 2 for the item that the client wants. All I need to do is delete all lines that don't have "CARTEIRA" (wallet) in it and left the header (the one that starts with 1), so this CSV will include only wallets purchase orders for those clients.

I can't use Excel because it mess with the 0's and other stuff inside the CSV (like the word "Cafe"... It will change the "e" to "é" because of Portuguese grammar) but I have no idea what program to use to delete those lines... and the CSV file is kinda huge.

I though of using VBA but I have no idea where to start... Notepad++ didn't have an option to "exclude entire line"... not that I could find anyway.

So, first sorry for the bad english, and second, If possible, I want to share this solution with my team that have 0 experience with programming :D .

Thank you kindly,

Kr4ft

Comment: Which column in your CSV file contains 'CARTEIRA'?

Comment: None of the lines in your sample include the word `CARTEIRA`, but you could probably use Power Query and a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows (or use PowerShell Core) you can use something like this to get going:

```
Import-Csv .\my-data.csv -Header ClientId, No, Code, Type -Delimiter ";" 
| Where-Object {$_.ClientId -EQ 1 -or ($_.ClientId -EQ 2 -and $_.Code -EQ "CNPJ")}
| Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" out.csv
```

Note that if your CSV file contains a header row then you can remove the `-Header` parameter.  Otherwise you'll have to specify every column in the `-Header` parameter